# Online tool to encrypt/decrypt messages for chatting in privacy

Tags: chat, encryption, hosted, privacy

Is there an online tool to encrypt and decrypt messages, so that it is possible to use a general purpose chat service (such as Facebook Messenger or WhatsApp) with relative privacy?

For example I type in the tool

> Hello how are you

Then the online encrypter tranlates the message to somehting mass-surveillence won't understand such as

> Rhwmd hwi hen cyu

Then my correspondent receives the message and decodes it and retries the original message.

For now I found https://www.latoilescoute.net/decodeur/ but actually it only uses encodings without a password so they're very weak. But at least it's better than nothing.

The tool should ideally be extremely easy to use for me to discuss with people which are less skilled with computers or software than I am.

Comment: Just wondering if that's not a contradiction: how to you get those messages to (and from) the online service to encrypt (and decrypt)? Crypting must happen locally if it should make sense, otherwise there's always a 3rd party involved that can follow your communication. "Mass surveilance" then just had to plug in to that service (or into any router between user and service) – which is common practice e.g. in the US.

Comment: @lzzy The thing is that nobody will be personally interested in what we say. I just want to avoid algorithms to automatically analise what we say. Even if the encryption is very easily defeatable, at least the messages won't be analyzed automatically. But you have a point.

Comment: If encryption is server-based, it's always easy to "automatically analyze". You just need to get hold of the server key (take a warrant and visit the hoster). If it's client-based, it's a lot harder to achieve unnoticed. But I take it I'm preaching the choir – and it's just the users who are unwilling … And as comments are not for discussion, I'll shut up now :)

Comment: What you are describing sounds similar to  [end-to-end encryption](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/End-to-end_encryption). It's better to use a [client that already supports it](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_instant_messaging_clients?oldformat=true#Messengers_with_client-to-client_encryption) than introducing another third party into the conversation